# Lock screen rotation for **ALL** Android Apps on a device

Tags: android, rotation, screen, orientation

this is my first post so please correct me if I do any mistake regarding rules :-)

Heres my problem:

I am trying to set a fixed screen rotation for all Apps on an Android device 
(not just my App). I searched a lot but found only solutions for single Apps.

I had the following Ideas:

1) Use the API ==> seems not possible

2) Change accelerometer values ==> seems not possible

3) virtually open a hardware keyboard  ==> seems not possible

Turning off autorotation keeps all Apps in portrait mode, but I would like all
Apps to be in landscape mode.

Can anybody help me please?

Answer (score 0):

At least for Android 4.2. (Nexus 7) you can hold device in landscape mode and then disable autorotation. Afterwards all apps work in landscape mode.

Comment: Does not work on Samsung Galaxy S3. Turning off autorotation forces portrait mode.